# Describe the set of all harmonic functions $u(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that the product $(x^2 −y^2)u(x,y)$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{C}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, harmonic-functions

Describe the set of all harmonic functions $u(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that the product $(x^2 −y^2)u(x,y)$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{C}.$

I have concluded that $xu_x = yu_y$.  Not sure how to proceed from here.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: next show that $u$ is (locally) a function of $xy$, i.e. is constant on the curves $xy = c$.